# compere max and min price using mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is sample html

```
<body>
<p>product name 
  <input type="text" name="productname">
</p>
<p>product type 
  <input type="text" name="producttype">
</p>
<p>
  <select name="select">

                                        <option value="300">$300 - $600</option>
                                        <option value="700">$700 - $1000</option>
                                        <option value="1000">$1000 plus</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

SQL QUERY

```
SELECT 
  SND.SELLER_ID, 
  SND.SELLER_NAME, 
  SND.SELLER_COUNTRY, 
  M.PRODUCT_ID, 
  M.PRODUCT_NAME, 
  M.PRODUCT_TYPE  
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE as M
JOIN SELLERS_TABLE as SND ON SND.SELLER_ID = M.SELLER_ID 
WHERE M.PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%$Rice%' 
   OR PRODUCT_TYPE LIKE '%CA_RICE%'
```

its really confusing me, how to add on  to select price  like all products from 300 to 600 like that.
and get products from 300 to 600 only. according to html selection

Comment: `WHERE ... AND <whatever your price column is> BETWEEN <lower boundary> AND <higher boundary>`...

Comment: Not sure of the point of the html. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if those values are hardcoded or if they are retrieved from a table in the database.

If they are hard coded you could use hardcoded logic, as in:

```
SELECT 
  SND.SELLER_ID, 
  SND.SELLER_NAME, 
  SND.SELLER_COUNTRY, 
  M.PRODUCT_ID, 
  M.PRODUCT_NAME, 
  M.PRODUCT_TYPE  
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE as M
JOIN SELLERS_TABLE as SND ON SND.SELLER_ID = M.SELLER_ID 
WHERE (M.PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%$Rice%' 
   OR PRODUCT_TYPE LIKE '%CA_RICE%')
  and :param = 300 and m.price > 300 and m.price < 700
   or :param = 700 and m.price between 700 and 1000
   or :param = 1000 and m.price > 1000
```

Asumming the parameter `param` is retrieved from the web page.

Comment: well. html was just an example. but wat i mean my select tag brings value of $300 so i want to get products from 300 to 600 or 1000 plus

Comment: something like `SELECT 
  SND.SELLER_ID, SND.SELLER_NAME, SND.SELLER_COUNTRY, M.PRODUCT_ID, M.PRODUCT_NAME, M.PRODUCT_TYPE  FROM
  PRODUCT_TABLE as M
  JOIN SELLERS_TABLE as SND ON SND.SELLER_ID = M.SELLER_ID WHERE M.PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%$Rice%', OR PRODUCT_TYPE LIKE '%CA_RICE%'
  AND M.PRICE BETWEEN HTML_VALUE AND HTML_VALUE OR M.PRICE > HTML_VALUE`